# how to calculate two row from date to end date in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I assign a bus for Maintenance :

```
$start_date='06/13/2017';
$end_date='06/17/2017';
```

Question: 1.)
If i assign that bus for tour between the date:

```
$form_start_date='06/12/2017';
$form_end_date='06/15/2017';
```

It want to show an error as the bus in Maintenance please choose another date or bus.

Question: 2.)
If i assign that bus for tour between the date:

```
$form_start_date='06/12/2017';
$form_end_date='06/19/2017';
```

It want to show an error as the bus in Maintenance please choose another date or bus.

Question: 3.)
If i assign that bus for tour between the date:

```
$form_start_date='06/14/2017';
$form_end_date='06/19/2017';
```

It want to show an error as the bus in Maintenance please choose another date or bus.

i am new to laravel. if any one know the answer(query) please let me know

Comment: Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.I guess that's all you really need to know.

Comment: where do you want to use checking time query? put codes of that file in your question

Comment: I use this Query in laravael

$maintance_bus = bus_maintance::where('id',$bus_id)->where('start_date', '<=', $form_start_date)->where('end_date', '>=', $form_end_date)->get();

It does not show any error, i used count() function for checking that query is working or not

Comment: How do you currently store the maintenance times and booking times?

Comment: I store in date format 06/13/2017